# c: convert hex to same value decimal number

Tags: c

i have

```
UINT8 year = 0x15;
```

and I want to get decimal value 15 in `UINT8 decYear` from `year`. How can I do it ? thankyou

background: I am ready day, month, year. I get value back 0x15, 0x10, 0x13 respectively for today. and I want to convert them to decimal values

Comment: You don't. All values are ultimately stored in *binary*, decimal or hexadecimal are only ways to present the values. The value you assign to `year` is binary `00010101`, and if you print it using decimal notation you will get `21`.

Comment: by the way @JoachimPileborg 0x15 is not 37 in decimal, it's 21

Comment: yes, lets say the value represented in hex format is actually representing a dec value. like here 0x15 is representing the decimal 15 (i.e. 2105). so how to convert it

Comment: Or do you mean that you want to use [Binary Coded Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)?

Comment: @user3061597 that doesn't make much sense, let's say you have year = 0xF, what is that supposed to represent in decimal?

Comment: there will never be a scenario like this. actually I am reading day, month, year and I get its value back in hex. and I want to convert it in the decimal. so it will always be between 0-9

Comment: you don't want to convert it, actually. can you post some code to make this clearer? I understand what you mean but I see no reason for you to want to do this

Comment: reason is ok lets say monjth value is taking a Byte. but it is always gonna be between 1-12 in decimal. So I can store its value in 4bits and save 4 bits for some other use. so that's why I want 0x10(October) to be converted to 10 dec and then I can store it in 4 bits

Comment: what if the year is 2016? You'll get 0xF and that won't make any sense

Comment: for 2016 I will get back 0x16

Comment: this logic is flawed from the start

Comment: yes, but its not in my control. I am getting this input so I have to make use of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The representation you are using is called [Binary Coded Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) and it's an old way of encoding values.

To get a "proper" decimal value you need to know how binary values work, and how to use the bitwise operators in C.

Lets say you have the BCD encoded value `0x15`, this is binary `00010101`. As you can see the `1` is stored in the high [*nibble*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) and the `5` in the low. Getting them out by themselves is an easy bitwise-and operation:

```
int year = 0x15;
int high_nibble = year & 0xf0;  // Gets the high nibble, i.e. `0x10`
int low_nibble = year & 0x0f;   // Gets the low nibble, i.e. `0x05`
```

Now you have two variables, one containing `0x10` and the other `0x05`. The hexadecimal value `0x05` is the same as the decimal value `5`, so nothing needs to be done with it. The other value needs some work to make it the decimal `10`. For this we simply shift it down four bits (`00010000` will become `00000001`) doing

```
high_nibble >> 4
```

and to "convert" it to decimal you multiply the value by `10` (`1 * 10 == 10`), and finally add the `5`.

To put it all together into a single expression:

```
int decYear = ((year & 0xf0) >> 4) * 10 + (year & 0x0f);
```

Comment: Nicely explained. Maybe explaining that decYear does not really contain a decimal value but the representation of that decimal value in binary would be an improvement. You already hint it with "proper" and "convert". Or maybe that is beyond the scope of the question. Anyways +1

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case you can use this

```
UINT8 year = 0x15;
UINT8 yearD = year%16+ (year/16)*10;
```

There's better solution using [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) encoding

```
 UINT8 yearD = ((year>>4)&0x0f)*10+ (year&0x0f);
```

Explanation:

Binary representation of `0x15` is `‭00010101‬`. We have high [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) with 1 (`0001`) and low nibble 5(`0101`). So final result is `higher nibble value *10 + value of lower nibble`. To get high nibble value we do 4 [shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift) right then [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with `0x0f`, 4 right shift take high nibble value to lower nibble and `bitwise and` with `0x0f` clear upper nibble, which is the real value of upper nibble. And to get lower nibble value we need to clear higher nibble value to do so we use `year&0x0f`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: `0x15` is `21` (5 x 16 ^ 0) + ( 1 x 16 ^ 1 ), not 15.

Secondly, try:

```
UINT8 year = 0x15;
printf("%d",year);
```

This is because, no value is saved as hex or decimal, but as binary, ultimately. The hex you used is but a representation for your system to be translated to binary, like `21` would be.

Making it output 15 would probably be very difficult and make the fact that you even entered it in hex superflous. Its like entering `21` and asking for us to contrive a way for the system to know you meant `15`

If you get a value in hex as return from something, try converting it into a string and just cutting off the `0x` part of it.

For example, if you get `0x15` as value, just read it in as string, and cut the 0x off with string operations.

Comment: 0x15 CAN be the decimal value 15. It can also be the decimal value 21. It can also be the NAK character. And many other things. It just depends on what it is representing. The OP uses an encoding where 0x15 IS the decimal value 15. He just failed to mention what that encoding is, maybe he does not even know since he is just learning. It likely is BCD.

Answer (score 0):

If 0x15 (in hexadecimal) does represent 15 (in decimal) then you are likely dealing with input in [BCD format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

In such a case converting from BCD to decimal(1) is done by extracting each nible of the input and adding them properly.
Our input is a byte of 8 bits.
The 4 less significative bits (the lower nibble) represent the units, a number from 0 to 9. Values from A to F (hexadecimal) are never used.
The 4 most significative bits  (the upper nibble) represent the tens. Also a number from 0 to 9.

If you extract them you get the decimal(1) value by the formula : tens*10 + units.
We can get the lower nibble with a binary mask : `year & 0x0F`
And the upper nibble with a right shift and the same binary mask : `(year>>4) & 0x0F`
The whole code is :

```
UINT8 year = 0x15;
assert ( ( (year>>4) & 0x0F ) < 10 );  // Ensure top nibble correctness
assert ( (year & 0x0F) < 10);         // Ensure low nibble correcness
int yearBin = ( (year>>4) & 0x0F ) * 10 + (year&0x0F);
printf("%d\n", (int)yearBin); // Print yearBin in decimal : 15 will be printed
printf("%x\n", (int)yearBin); // Print yearBin in hexadecimal :
                        // 0x15 will not be printed. 0xF will be printed.
```

(1) Actually, we are not converting from BCD to decimal. We are converting from BCD to binary (most likely in 2-complement). It is the choice of conversion parameters in printf what makes it be printed in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

A "hexadecimal value that contains no letters" is [Binary Coded Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) (BCD). You can convert BCD to decimal like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t bcd2dec(uint8_t bcdval)
{
    return (bcdval >> 4) * 10 + (bcdval & 0xF);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Day   %u\n", bcd2dec(0x13));
    printf("Month %u\n", bcd2dec(0x10));
    printf("Year  %u\n", bcd2dec(0x15));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Day   13
Month 10
Year  15
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want to get 15 from 0x15.

You can use the following method:

```
char buffer[4];
UINT8 year = 0x15;

sprintf(buffer, "%x", year);
```

if you print buffer, you get "15" as a string. You can then do:

```
UINT8 decYear = atoi(buffer);
```